# Trying to mock nfcManager using react native testing library nfcManager.start() functionality

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-nfc-manager

I am developing an android app that requires to read nfc tags, so I am using the `react-native-nfc-manager`. However, I have come across two issues that I could not figure out at all.

- What does the `nfcManager.start()` function actually do? I realized that the app was working even if I remove it from the top of the method. If I try to check what the promise returns, it returns `undefined`
- I want to test the page, so I try to mock `nfcManager`. However, I always get this issue  `TypeError: _reactNativeNfcManager.default.start is not a function` or `TypeError: _reactNativeNfcManager.default.isSupported is not a function` etc with all the functions of the interface.

What I try to do and get the above mentioned errors is

`const mockNfcManager = jest.fn();`

`jest.mock("react-native-nfc-manager", ()=>({  NfcManagerModule: { start: mockNfcManager, }, }));`

and then render the component and check if `expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Answer (score 0):

```
nfcManager
  .start({
    onSessionClosedIOS: () => {},
  })
  .then(result => {})
  .catch(error => {
    console.warn('device does not support nfc!');
  });
```

Comment: Yeah fair point, but it prints `undefined` haha